# NextJS 13 - Retrieving POST data in server side component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have installed a brand new nextJS project, with a very basic src/app/page.js:

```
export default function Home(props) {

    const {fuzzySearchText, actor, type, studio} = props

    return (
        <main className={styles.main}>
            <div className="search">
                    <h2>Search Database</h2>

                    <form action="/" method='POST'>
                    <input type="text" name='fuzzySearchText' placeholder='fuzzySearchText'/>
                    <input type="text" name='actor' placeholder='actor'/>
                    <input type="text" name='type' placeholder='type'/>
                    <input type="text" name='studio' placeholder='studio'/>
                    <input type="submit" value='Search' />
                    </form>

                    <h4>Output</h4>
                    <div>fuzzy {fuzzySearchText}</div>
                    <div>act {actor}</div>
                    <div>type {type}</div>
                    <div>studi {studio}</div>

            </div>

            <SearchResults
                FuzzySearchText={fuzzySearchText}
                Actor={actor}
                Type={type}
                Studio={studio}
            />

        </main>
    )
}


export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

    const {fuzzySearchText, actor, type, studio} = context

  return {
    props: {
            fuzzySearchText, actor, type, studio
        }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

I want to be able to submit the form (POST or GET) and get the data straight into the component.  Is that possible in NextJS 13?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to submit to a server component where you can display your search params as well as search results. But here's a work around:

```
'use client';

export default function Home() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({fuzzySearchText: ''});
  const [results, setResults] = React.useState(null);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch('/path/to/your/api');
    setResults(response.json());
  }

  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <div className="search">
        <h2>Search Database</h2>

        <form method='POST' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name='fuzzySearchText'
            placeholder='fuzzySearchText'
            value={formData.fuzzySearchText}
            onChange={(e) => setFormData({...formData, fuzzySearchText: e.target.value})}
          />
          ...
        </form>

        <h4>Output</h4>
        <div>fuzzy {formData.fuzzySearchText}</div>
        <div>act {formData.actor}</div>
        <div>type {formData.type}</div>
        <div>studi {formData.studio}</div>
      </div>

      {results && <SearchResults results={results} />}
    </main>
  );
}
```

NextJS 13 beta docs are still not very clear (work in progress). Lots of unstable and ongoing changes are made frequently. Hopefully, the docs will be updated very soon and there'll be clear instructions for what you're trying to do. :)